# What changes do I need to make to the source code of catboost to increase the max_depth beyond 16?

Tags: python, decision-tree, setup.py, depth, catboost

I want to use deeper trees for my business problem but catboost has a limit of 16 on tree depth. I went through the code and found the piece where this has been hardcoded. This line in [catboost/private/libs/options/oblivious_tree_options.cpp](https://github.com/catboost/catboost/blob/master/catboost/private/libs/options/oblivious_tree_options.cpp):

`const ui32 maxFullBinaryTreeDepth = 16;`

Can I simply change this to 64 and then run setup.py? Or there will be other dependencies and can cause any issue?

Comment: Well, why not just try?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a hard limit in the CatBoost.

I assume that you want to tune the CatBoost algorithm for better performance. You can try to tune different parameters, for example, `learning_rate`, `rsm`, `l2_leaf_reg`. From my experience depth above 12 is very high. Maybe that's why CatBoost developers set a hard limit?

You can also try MLJAR AutoML (I'm the main contributor) https://github.com/mljar/mljar-supervised to tune CatBoost. MLJAR has two options for tuning:

- random search + hill-climibing
- TPE optimization (from Optuna framework)

Example code:

```py
automl=AutoML(algorithms=["CatBoost"], mode="Compete")
automl.fit(X, y)
```

or tuning with Optuna:

```py
automl=AutoML(algorithms=["CatBoost"], mode="Optuna")
automl.fit(X, y)
```

All models in MLJAR are documented. After AutoML training you can reuse the hyperparameters from AutoML (if you want).

Comment: I want to build deeper trees because I want to use the information from the built tree for something. Catboost is the only algo which uses symmetric trees and that is precisely what I want, but with more available depth. Any further suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: You can try to change the limit in CatBoost and compile that package. May I ask what would you like to get from such a deep tree?